# Strict standards: Non-static method should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in php file

Tags: php, android, json

I have a rudimentary knowledge of PHP, and I am facing an error retrieving a JSON object from my PHP web service

```
Strict standards: Non-static method API_USERS::getRecordByID() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in .../lists.php on line 1387
```

and thus because of this error I am unable to parse my JSON object properly and get this error in my Android Studio logcat

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

is there a way I can get rid of this error? This is the PHP I am trying to use:

```
  <?php
    define('IEM_PATH', '../admin/com');
    require_once('../admin/includes/config.php');
    require_once('../admin/com/lib/IEM.class.php');
    require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/DBFACTORY.class.php');
    require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/baseAPI.class.php');
    require_once ('../admin/com/lib/API/USERS.class.php');
    require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/baseRecord.class.php');
    require_once ('../admin/com/lib/record/Users.class.php');

        function GetLists($userid = 0, $getUnconfirmedCount = false) {

            $userid = $_REQUEST['userID'];
            if (!$userid) {
                trigger_error('This user object is not loaded with any user.... You will need to supply the userid as a parameter.', E_USER_NOTICE);
                return false;
            }


            if (!$userid) {
                $userid = $this->userid;
            }

            require_once('../admin/functions/api/lists.php');

            $listapi = new Lists_API();
            $returnA =  $listapi->GetListByUserID($userid, $getUnconfirmedCount);
            $returnResult1 = array();
            foreach ($returnA as $key => $value) { 
                //$lists[] = $key;
                $returnResult["contactList"][] = array("listID" => $returnA[$key]['listid'], "name" => $returnA[$key]['name']);
            }
            $returnResult["success"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($returnResult);
        }

        GetLists();
```

and this is the code which I believe to be the source of error (line 1387)

```
$user = API_USERS::getRecordById($userid);
```

Comment: Please post the line of code that presents this error, or some indicator of where in your code this is happening. I assume it's in one of your included files.

Comment: according to the output of the browser I think the source of the error was from this file `require_once('../admin/functions/api/lists.php');` and I have edited my question to include the line of the code that apparently contributed the error

Comment: Can you post the code inside that method, too?

Answer (score 0):

This code was copied from a class:

```
$userid = $this->userid;
```

You don't have $this when you're not in a (non static) member function.

just delete these 3 lines:

```
    if (!$userid) {
        $userid = $this->userid;
    }
```

Comment: how do you suggest i should modify my codes to either get a value for $this?

Comment: I tried to delete the three lines, but the error is still there, `Non-static method API_USERS::getRecordByID() should not be called statically`

Comment: sorry! i missed it out. edited my question to include it already :-)

Comment: no it's not, you just dropped it at the end of your question, out of context, to show "this line causes the error"

Answer (score 0):

Your methode getRecordByID() should by declared like this :

```
public static function getRecordByID() {
...
}
```

Or You should call it after instanciate the API_USERS class like :

```
$instance = new API_USERS();
$instance->getRecordByID();
```